# Overlapping Book-Page Range

Tags: c#

I have a set of `Book-Page(6794-47)` range. Please note that page limit is not confirm.

Now I want to check the overlapping of  book page range in multiple range list

Please check below example.

Below is my parameter range.

```
Start Book-Page Range ---- (21205-41) 

End Book-Page Range ---- (21206-1674)
```

and want to extract the overlapped ranges from a range list
Range List e.g

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21206-974 to 21206-5196 (overlapping since page 974 lies between parameter range)
--
21206-1974 to 21206-5196 (not overlapping)

21207-74 to 21207-193 (not overlapping)

21204-71 to 21205-100   (overlapping since page 100 lies between parameter range)
--
21205-31-21205-59 (overlapping)
--
```

Now I need to get the all overlapping from list range. Please help me.

Regards
Arun Bhandari

Comment: What have you attempted? Post some code and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Book-Page(6794-47) range" ?

Answer (score 0):

If the pages numbers are in a list you can always do a union statement.